# How can vector elements be incremented?

Tags: c++, vector

Ok I’m gonna rewrite this question because it doesn’t have enough clarification

```
    int x = 10;
    std::vector <int> result1;
    do
    {
    x - -;

        result1.push_back(1);

    } while (x > 0)
```

And then I’ll have a vector of 10 elements. Now my question is. How can I increment each element to have a value of 10?

Comment: What you want is not clear from your description. Can you show what the final vector should be, as well as how the loop ends?

Comment: Well I was using this more as a test example. The desired size of the vector or time of the loop was not of concern to me, just having the knowledge to increment the added elements is enough for me. Should I make that clear or adjust the code anyway? And may I ask how is it not clear?

Comment: It's not clear which values in the vector you want to increment. Is it only the one you add each time in the loop, or is it all the elements that are currently in the vector? Also, remove the `sleep` bit since it's irrelevant. Also, if `outcome1` is hard coded for the demo, why write the `if` in the demo?

Comment: I want each value that has been pushed back (or will be because of the loop) to be incremented.

Comment: It may just be a language barrier for me, but I'm really not sure what you want the loop to do. It would be *very* helpful if you just picked some random size for the vector, and show what the resulting vector's values should be.

Comment: Yes, I agree with cigien

Comment: The candidate interpretations I see that you want the resulting vector to be (1,2,3,4,5) (add increasing numbers to it) or (5,4,3,2,1) (increment vector contents after every step). Which one is it? Or do you want some other result?

Comment: So you want the vector to contain 10 elements, each with the value 10? In general, do you want `x` elements with the value `x`?

Comment: @cigien, Yes I do.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop to fill up elements of a `vector` with the same value. If you want the `vector` to contain `x` elements with the value `x`, you can use a `vector` constructor like this

```
std::vector<int> result1(x, x);
```

where the 1st argument is the number of elements, and the 2nd argument is the value each of those elements should have.